# find if point lies in given graph

Tags: geometry

i have following question and please help me,suppose that we have region on coordinante  systems bounded by  lines $x=0$,$=0$,$y=1-x$
we have to enter  some point let's sat M,with  x,y coordinates,my aim is to  show if given point  lies  on this bounded interval,just one  thing which i didn't understand is that,should i use  theorem of right triangle or what?i need  a little explanation ,for example i want to write program and want to understand  correctly mathematical definition of this problem

Comment: Have you made a drawing of your region? You should be able to construct appropriate inequalities from that.

Comment: You're missing something in the second equation. Also, do they have periods where you come from, or only commas?

Comment: only commas,graph of this interval is  just right triangle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to approach this sort of questions, is to think about inequalities geometrically. You don't want to start messing around with distances and properties of triangles. Instead, you can view each line as a "boundary", and the other lines as the "direction" of the inequality. The best way is to start with a picture:

[y=1-x in google](http://www.google.ca/#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&source=hp&q=y+%3D+1-x&pbx=1&oq=y+%3D+1-x&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=3&gs_upl=1815l3953l0l4167l11l9l0l0l0l0l107l107l0.1l1l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=9b2333bea0cc8252&biw=1280&bih=619)

Now, take your first line equation $x = 0$ that's just the $x$-axis. Looking at the picture, the region you want extends to the right along this axis, so you set $x \geq 0$.
The second equation is (I assume) $y = 0$. Looking at the picture, the region you want extends to the top, along this axis, so you set $y \geq 0$.
Finally, the last boundary is $y = 1-x$. Looking the the picture, you want the points to be *under* that line, so you set $y \leq 1-x$.

You're done, a point with coordinates $(a,b)$ will be in the triangle iff $a, b$ are both non-negative, *and* $b \leq 1-a$.

Comment: thanks very much i was out,thanks @Gal  for explanation